# Show that $\sqrt{abc}$ is irrational if $a, b, c$, and $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}$ are irrational.

Tags: irrational-numbers

Assume $a$,$b$,$c$ are the irrational numbers, and $\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt c$ is irrational number.
Show that $\sqrt{abc}$ is irrational number.
Please help me this problem, thank you for watching!

Comment: Counter Example: $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit No it's not, because $2,3,6$ are rational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not true. However, the counterexamples in the comments don't work. Note the requirement that $a, b,$ and $c$ (**not** just $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$, and $\sqrt{c}$) should be irrational.

For a correct counterexample, take
$$
a = b = c = \sqrt[3]{4}.
$$
These are irrational (this can be proven similarly to the irrationality of the square root of $2$). 
Then,
$$
\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} = \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{2} = 3\sqrt[3]{2},
$$
which is also irrational -- because $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational (which can again be proven similarly to irrationality of the square root of $2$).

However,
$$
\sqrt{abc} = \sqrt{4} = 2,
$$
which is rational.

Comment: Hans Engler's counterexample looks good to me. $\sqrt 2$ and $2^{1/4}$ are irrational, aren't they?

Comment: If $a = 2^{1/2}$ and $b = c = 2^{1/4}$, then $\sqrt{abc} = \sqrt{2}$, which is irrational. So that isn't a counterexample.

Comment: @TonyK I think Hans meant rather that $a = 2$, $b = c = \sqrt{2}$. Either way, that counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: My counterexample referred to an earlier version of the post where the claim was that $\sqrt{a}bc$ is irrational. That has been fixed by the OP and I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks for the clarification, I have removed the negative reference in my answer :)